# Nested_attributes dont appear in my params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, nested-forms, parameters

I'm trying to include `nested_form` in one of my model new form.

```
<%= form_for :master_box, url: master_boxes_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :number %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :number %>

    <%= f.fields_for :orders do |o| %>
        <fieldset>
            <%= o.label :number, "Number" %>
            <%= o.text_field :number %>
        </fieldset> 
    <% end %>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I don't know why when I submit to create my masterbox, my params don't contain `orders_attributes`.

Here's my models :

```
class MasterBox < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :orders
end


class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  belongs_to :master_box
end
```

and my strong parameters :

```
def master_box_params
  params.require(:master_box).permit(:number, :number_orders, orders_attributes: [:number])
end
```

It is pretty simple but I don't understand why I don't have `orders_attributes` in my params.
I have this instead, only "orders" : 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the first line of your form to:

```
<%= form_for @master_box, url: master_boxes_path do |f| %>
```

and also passing through the id in your params:

```
def master_box_params
  params.require(:master_box).permit(:number, :number_orders, orders_attributes: [:id, :number])
end
```

Comment: It was exactly my problem. Thx @adrianmann, i waste a lot of times on it .. :

Answer (score 0):

`fields_for :orders` creates the `orders` parameter that you are seeing. This bit of your strong parameters `orders_attributes: [:number]` is allowing the `numbers` attribute of `orders` to be passed through. You should be looking at the `orders` parameter that you are receiving. That's where the data you want is.